# Images array only shows once

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm sure nothing is wrong with [react-dropzone](https://github.com/paramaggarwal/react-dropzone) works great and when I drop a file, array shows in my console:

```
getInitialState() {
 return{files: []}
},
onDrop(files) {
 this.setState({files: files});
 console.log(files);
},

render(){
 var attachedFiles = this.state.files;
 return(
  {attachedFiles.map((file, idx) =>
    <img key={idx} src={file.preview} />
   )}
)
}
```

**When two files are dropped, in console it shows as**

```
>[File]
>[File]
```

But only the last file is shown. Am I not iterating correctly?

**Edited:**

I have noticed that my files state only shows one array no matter if I dropped more than one file.

Comment: Make sure you return your elements when mapping the array.

Comment: @JanKlimo Hi. But what do you mean exactly?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, I think you'll need a `return` statement in your `map` function. Your `render` function also needs to return your data wrapped in a single parent node, something like:

```
render(){
  var attachedFiles = this.state.files;
  var imagesNodes = attachedFiles.map((file, idx) => {
    return <img key={idx} src={file.preview} />;
  });

  return (
    <div className="imagesList">
      {imagesNodes}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I do remembered doing that but the files state still shows only one array. `files: Array[1]` Maybe a bug with the package?

Comment: That sounds good. The `files` array should hold all the files you dropped. So if you dropped two, the length of this array should be 2. Take a look at what's inside of this array.

Comment: I see `>0: File{...}` When tried to expand that, I get `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation` This is when I dropped two files. This is in the React addon for chrome. But chrome console still shows length as 1

Comment: I see. I realized you'll need a parent node in your `render`. Wondering if that causes a problem as well? See my latest edit to my answer.

Comment: Hi Jan. I think there is a bug with the package. Im still having the same issue. Still one array.